# Get certain values from a list of pdfs

Tags: r, pdf

I would like to:

- get certain data in page 2 for every element in a list created (pdfs files)
- data from page 2 (for Bond Futures **CGB** ... column 2, 11 and 16)
- create a data frame aggregating all this data

Year |  Month |  Metric

2013   January   Monthly Volume

2013   January   Month End Open Interest

2013   January  Transactions

I have tried the following but haven't reached far at all - my apologies.

```
library(rvest)
library(pdftools)
library(tidyverse)

filepath <- "~R Working Directory/CanadianFutures" 

files <- list.files(path = filepath, pattern = '*.pdf')
```

The variable **files** contains the list:

[1] "1301_stats_en.pdf" "1302_stats_en.pdf" "1303_stats_en.pdf" "1304_stats_en.pdf" "1305_stats_en.pdf" "1306_stats_en.pdf"
 [7] "1307_stats_en.pdf" "1308_stats_en.pdf" "1309_stats_en.pdf" "1310_stats_en.pdf" "1311_stats_en.pdf" "1312_stats_en.pdf"
[13] "1401_stats_en.pdf" "1402_stats_en.pdf" "1403_stats_en.pdf" "1404_stats_en.pdf" "1405_stats_en.pdf" "1406_stats_en.pdf".....[61] "1801_stats_en.pdf" "1802_stats_en.pdf" "1803_stats_en.pdf" "1804_stats_en.pdf" "1805_stats_en.pdf"

I have tried the following to get page 2 for each pdf but totally lost:

```
all <- lapply(files, function(x) {
    txt <- pdf_text(filenames)
    page_2 <- txt[2]
})
```

I get the following:

*Error in normalizePath(pdf, mustWork = TRUE) : 
   path[1]="1301_stats_en.pdf": No such file or directory*

All the pdfs in my list have the same consistent formatting.
Here is an example of the pdf https://www.m-x.ca/f_stat_en/1401_stats_en.pdf

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your working directory is the same as where you stored your files:

```
getwd()
```

Another option is to make your list of files displayed as complete directories.

```
 files <- list.files(filepath, pattern = '*.pdf', full.names = T)
 >files
 [1] "Downloads/naamloze map//1401_stats_en-2.pdf"
 [2] "Downloads/naamloze map//1401_stats_en.pdf"  

 PDFreader <- function(x){
 t <- pdf_text (x)
 page_2 <- t
 }

 lapply(files, PDFreader)
```

returns

```
 [[1]]
 [1]..... text....

 [[2]]
 [1]..... text....
```

Good luck

Comment: Thats great. It works perfectly. I will now try to do the next step of creating a data frame with the selected data. Thank you